PlatformException when loading FirebaseOptions from resource in Flutter
I’m working on a Flutter project with Firebase integration, and I’ve encountered a PlatformException that I’m struggling to resolve. The exception is thrown when the app attempts to load FirebaseOptions from the resource. Here’s the error message:
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(java.lang.Exception: Failed to load FirebaseOptions from resource. Check that you have defined values.xml correctly., Exception, Cause: null, Stacktrace: java.lang.Exception: Failed to load FirebaseOptions from resource. Check that you have defined values.xml correctly.
    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.lambda$optionsFromResource$4$io-flutter-plugins-firebase-core-FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin(FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:207)
    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
, null))

I could not find values.xml. I’ve also ensured that Firebase.initializeApp() is called before any other Firebase-related operations.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Ensuring the values.xml file is correctly placed in the android/app/src/main/res/values directory.
Updating all Firebase dependencies in pubspec.yaml.
Running flutter clean and flutter pub get to clear any potential build issues.
Testing the app on both an emulator and a real device.

Make sure you have this file:
Also Add this to assets in pubspec.yaml file.
project_application\android\app\google-services.json
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Load the google-services.json file as a string
  String googleServicesJsonString =
      await rootBundle.loadString('android\\app\\google-services.json');
  print("google_Services_Json_String: $googleServicesJsonString");

  // Parse the JSON String into a JSON
  final googleServicesJson = jsonDecode(googleServicesJsonString);
  final projectId = googleServicesJson['project_info']["project_id"];
  print("projectId: $projectId");
  final messagingSenderId =
      googleServicesJson['project_info']["project_number"];
  print("messagingSenderId: $messagingSenderId");
  final storageBucket = googleServicesJson['project_info']["storage_bucket"];
  print("storageBucket: $storageBucket");
  final appId =
      googleServicesJson['client'][0]["client_info"]["mobilesdk_app_id"];
  print("appId: $appId");
  final apiKey = googleServicesJson['client'][0]["api_key"][0]["current_key"];
  print("apiKey: $apiKey");

  // Create a FirebaseOptions object from the extracted configuration
  FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: apiKey,
    appId: appId,
    messagingSenderId: messagingSenderId,
    projectId: projectId,
    storageBucket: storageBucket,
  );

  // Initialize Firebase with the options
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: options);

  // Log or print a message here to verify initialization
  print('Firebase app is initialized!');

  runApp(MyApp());
}

Remove print statements if you want.

is it safe to expose that json as an asset?
